# Запуск и остановка потоков последовательно (BackgroundWorker)

Tags: c#

Добрый день.

Как возможно добиться того чтобы сначала завершался первый поток, потом второй, третий ну и т.д. Т.е. завершать потоки по порядку или отдавать результат из RunWorkerCompleted по порядку.

Спасибо.

Пример кода:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    const int ThreadCount = 10;

    static readonly Random r = new Random();
    static readonly object sync = new object();
    static readonly CountdownEvent countdown = new CountdownEvent(ThreadCount);
    static readonly BackgroundWorker[] workers = new BackgroundWorker[ThreadCount];

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.CursorVisible = false;
        Console.WriteLine("Starting the workers...");

        for (int i = 0; i < workers.Length; i++)
        {
            workers[i] = new BackgroundWorker();
            workers[i].WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            workers[i].WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            workers[i].DoWork += DoWork;
            workers[i].ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
            workers[i].RunWorkerCompleted += RunWorkerCompleted;
            workers[i].RunWorkerAsync(i + 1);
        }

        while (!countdown.Wait(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)))
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
                Array.ForEach(workers, w => w.CancelAsync());

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, workers.Length + 1);
        Console.ResetColor();
        Console.WriteLine("All workers finished!\r\nPress any key to continue...");
        Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    static void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        e.Result = e.Argument;

        int progress = 0;
        do
        {
            worker.ReportProgress(progress, e.Argument);
            int interval;
            lock (r)
                interval = r.Next(1000);
            Thread.Sleep(interval);
        } 
        while (progress++ < 100 && !worker.CancellationPending);
    }

    static void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        int x = e.ProgressPercentage * 40 / 100 + 5;
        int y = (int)e.UserState;
        var color = (ConsoleColor)(y + 1 % Enum.GetValues(typeof(ConsoleColor)).Length);

        lock (sync)
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = color;
            Console.SetCursorPosition(0, y);
            Console.Write("{0,3}%", e.ProgressPercentage);
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
            Console.Write('\u2592');
        }
    }

    static void RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        countdown.Signal();
    }
 }
```

Comment: Пример кода следовало бы сделать покороче. Зачем вам это нужно? Возможно, вы выбрали неправильный путь решения задачи.

Comment: А зачем вам это? Неужели недостаточно просто опрашивать результат в нужном порядке?

Comment: Прошу прощения за долгий ответ, только что добрался до компьютера, т.к. я обучаюсь (не для вуза, а для себя) просто хотелось бы понять алгоритм завершения потоков последовательно если каждый поток занимает рандомное количество времени на выполнение.

Comment: Благодарю, то что нужно.

Comment: @z668, если вам нужно последовательное выполнение, то зачем делать несколько потоков? Пусть один поток вытаскивает задачи из очереди и выполняет их.

Comment: Код представленный выше не мой, на его основе делаю для обучения C# в целом и потокам в частности простейший парсер, просто чтобы научиться. Если сделать в один поток - будет намного проще, но гораздо дольше.

Comment: >> Если сделать в один поток - будет намного проще, но гораздо дольше

Каким образом оно будет дольше, если ваши потоки выполняют задачи последовательно, а не параллельно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам точно нужно именно так? Этого *можно* добиться, например, заведя по [`AutoResetEvent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx)'у в каждом из потоков, и дожидаясь `n`-го event'а в конце (`n+1`)-го потока. Но обычно порядок окончания работы потоков не играет роли.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще зачем много worker'ов создавать. По-моему достаточно назначить одному несколько обработчиков

```
worker.DoWork += onDoWork1;
worker.DoWork += onDoWork2;
```